# Multiple socket client with single machine on Network

Tags: java, sockets, synchronization

**Requirement:**
    I will get file from the server (Web application) and I have to print it using socket client. There will be 20+ users who will be connected to printing machine. Below is the sample class to print file.

ServerClient.Java

```
public class ServerClient
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintTest printTest = new PrintTest();
            printTest.print();
        } catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

PrintTest.java

```
public class PrintTest
{
    String fileOne = "D:/1.hpgl";

    public void print() throws IOException
    {
        Socket socket = null;
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.4.234", 9100);
            System.out.println("isConnected :- " + socket.isConnected());
            printFile(socket, fileOne);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void printFile(Socket socket, String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

            BufferedReader keyRead = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String fname = keyRead.readLine();

            OutputStream ostream = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);
            pwrite.println(fname);

            pwrite.close();
            keyRead.close();
        } catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Problem:**
When I will run this program is one machine it works fine, but when all users run same program in all 20 machine it gives execption of connection.

**Error:**

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at com.azilen.sockettest.PrintTest.print(PrintTest.java:32)
    at com.azilen.sockettest.ServerClient.main(ServerClient.java:20)
```

Comment: The code you show is not relevant to the error you show. The connection is refused, which can have many causes. Try researching the error and show your server code. Perhaps the server socket has a small backlog and doesn't accept new connections fast enough.

Comment: @CodeCaster : I understand, but when I try to run 2 program's parallel in two different machine then only error come, so it means I am not able to connect to machine with 2 separate socket object at a single time. that's where I am stucked.. :(

Comment: What part of my previous comment didn't you understand? The server is not accepting any new connections, so the problem is in the server code.

Comment: @CodeCaster: There is no server code, I am connecting my code 
(new Socket("192.168.4.234", 9100);) to Hardware which is a plotter machine to print.

Comment: Then the hardware supports only one connection at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion in comments we can extract the following problem statement:

*"I have a plotter machine, to which I want to send `.hpgl` files over a socket connection form a client application I'm developing. This works fine, as long as one client connects to the plotter at the same time. How can I let multiple clients send files to the plotter at the same time?"*

This means you'll have to either configure the plotter to accept multiple simultaneous connections, or if that isn't possible, you'll have to implement a service that sits between the clients and the plotter which implements queuing.

So instead of letting your client application connect directly to the plotter, you insert a service that acts as a buffer:

1. Any client connects to your service.
2. Service receives the file from the client.
3. Service queues the file data in some sort of internal queue.
4. Pop the oldest file off the top of the queue.
5. Wait until the connection to the plotter is available.
6. Send the file to the plotter.
7. Go to 4.

Steps 1-3 will require some form of synchronization (allowing multiple clients to connect to your service at the same time), while steps 4-7 will do what your current code does.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: Excellent..Just one concern, Separate service seems like dedicated machine which handles the request and send to plotter in synchronize form. Agree but any other option if client is not agree with "Separate service" solution... Any other way Hardware can have multiple connection ?

Comment: @EJP I used a blockquote to let it stand out that that text was not part of my answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster : ok Thanks a lot

Comment: @CodeCaster: One question, if I print ".hpgl" file using socket, is there any option to get printing status, so once printing will be done I can close the socket connection ?

Comment: @Harshil I'm sorry, but again I'll have to refer you to the manual that came with the hardware. I don't know.

Comment: @CodeCaster: alright and don't be sorry your answer is really helpful.. thanks mate